# Cut half-depth recess into underside of ikea cupboard top

Tags: carpentry

I'm looking to install a wireless charger into a chest of drawers that I have from ikea.

On the underside of the top of the chest of drawers I want to carve out 10mm of the 19mm thickness to ensure that the wireless charger can work more effectively. Doesn't need to be pretty as you can't see the underside, just needs enough space to fit the wireless charger.

What is the best way to achieve this without showing any damage from the top of the chest of drawers?

What tools will I need?

**EDIT**

Just incase, you can read here for more details: https://www.theverge.com/2021/9/19/22677980/ikea-sjomarke-wireless-qi-charging-existing-furniture

Also there is a 4mm piece of glass aswell as the wood, hence the need to carve some of it out.

Comment: Why do you need 10mm out of the underside of a chest top for a charger to "work more effectively" ?

Comment: If you can get at it, a router would be your best choice. Showing a picture might help.

Comment: are you rolling your own docking drawer?  https://dockingdrawer.com

Comment: @RMDman - the less material between the charger and the phone the more effective it is.

Comment: @Gil - forgive me, I'm not really sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger - no, see edit

Comment: @Cheetah, Gil is referring to a [woodworking router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(woodworking)) which can be used to shave exact depths out of wood.

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested, the best power tool for carving a recess to a specific depth is a router with a suitable bit. And given the material these are made of, that's probably the best tool for the task, period.

Lots of info on the web about how to use these effectively. They're very versatile tools, and fairly cheap. Unfortunately the versitility comes with buying an endless set of accessories to make them better at each task, but for this one operation a small plunge router and a single plunge bit will do the job, with a bit of care.

Comment: You could tack fences on the bottom  to prevent run-away router syndrome - probably a good idea for a beginner, else plenty of practice on scraps  (which you can usually get for free  from a kitchen furniture factory) routers throw chips, are noisy, and dusty, so eye, ear, and lung protection reccomended.

Comment: Or build a template and use a guided router bit... But I felt that was getting into the range of s tool-usage tutorial, and there are lots of sites and videos (and owner's manuals) that teach router use better than I could in a short answer.